# cmake reuse ExternalProject - DEPENDS does not work?

Tags: dependencies, cmake

Consider the following situation: I want to include a certain library via `ExternalProject_Add`. I want to build both release and debug libraries. My plan was to build the release libraries first and then reuse the downloaded source code for building the debug libraries. I do not want to download the source code twice. The relevant part from my CMakeLists.txt looks this:

```
ExternalProject_Add(
installSFMLRelease
            PREFIX ${TMPDIR}
            DOWNLOAD_DIR ${TMPDIR}/SFML
            GIT_REPOSITORY git://github.com/LaurentGomila/SFML.git
            GIT_TAG 2.0
            CMAKE_ARGS -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH=${SFML_INSTALL_PREFIX}
            CMAKE_GENERATOR ${CMAKE_GENERATOR}
            UPDATE_COMMAND "")

ExternalProject_Add(
installSFMLDebugAndDocs
            DEPENDS installSFMLRelease
            URL file://${TMPDIR}/SFML
            SOURCE_DIR ${TMPDIR}/SFML
            CMAKE_ARGS -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH=${SFML_INSTALL_PREFIX} -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE:STRING=Debug -DSFML_BUILD_DOC:BOOL=TRUE)
```

Guess what? It doesn't work. CMake fails with

```
3>CUSTOMBUILD : CMake error : The source directory "C:/Windows/Temp/SFML" does not appear to contain CMakeLists.txt.
```

The problem here is, that the directory does in fact not contain anything, because `installSFMLRelease` was not run before. How can I get the `DEPENDS`-section right?

Answer (score 0):

I tried that with libgit; git clones straight into 
${TMPDIR}/src/installLIBGITRelease
without using DOWNLOAD_DIR, so there's no CMakeLists in DOWNLOAD_DIR.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I'm not sure that your objectives will be met here.  If you build installSFMLRelease from MSVC in Debug mode, then you'll get a Debug build of this.  And vice-versa for a Release build of installSFMLDebugAndDocs.  The `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE` variable has no effect on multi-configuration generators like MSVC.

You may be better to specify different install paths for the different configurations?

Nonetheless, to answer your question, the `DOWNLOAD_DIR` argument only applies when used in conjunction with the `URL` arg I believe.  The docs for [`ExternalProject`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.11/cmake.html#module%3aExternalProject) don't really make this clear, but [this article](http://www.kitware.com/media/html/BuildingExternalProjectsWithCMake2.8.html) perhaps sheds a bit more light.

To fix this, I think you can skip specifying `DOWNLOAD_DIR` for installSFMLRelease, skip the entire download phase for installSFMLDebugAndDocs and instead retrieve the value of `SOURCE_DIR` for installSFMLRelease and pass this to the Debug version:

```
ExternalProject_Add(
    installSFMLRelease
    PREFIX ${TMPDIR}
    DOWNLOAD_DIR ${TMPDIR}/SFML
    GIT_REPOSITORY git://github.com/LaurentGomila/SFML.git
    GIT_TAG 2.0
    CMAKE_ARGS -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH=${SFML_INSTALL_PREFIX}
    CMAKE_GENERATOR ${CMAKE_GENERATOR}
    UPDATE_COMMAND "")

ExternalProject_Get_Property(installSFMLRelease source_dir)

ExternalProject_Add(
    installSFMLDebugAndDocs
    DEPENDS installSFMLRelease
    DOWNLOAD_COMMAND ""
    URL file://${TMPDIR}/SFML
    SOURCE_DIR ${TMPDIR}/SFML
    SOURCE_DIR ${source_dir}
    CMAKE_ARGS -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH=${SFML_INSTALL_PREFIX}
               -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE:STRING=Debug
               -DSFML_BUILD_DOC:BOOL=TRUE)
```